# Count Rows with Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I am going to count rows based on the values of two columns (i.e., count if the Priority is "1" and Status is "not defined"). Here is an example:

| Priority | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | implemented |
| 0 | implemented |
| 1 | not defined |
| 0 | not defined |
| 0 | implemented |
| 1 | not defined |
| 1 | implemented |
| 1 | implemented |

which I would like to get 2 because there are only two rows with Priority = 1 and Status = "not defined".

I tried the following but not successful in this regard:

`=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTA(M3:M20))*(J3:J20="not defined"))`

Comment: Have you tried COUNTIFS?

Comment: ^^^^^^ `=COUNTIFS(M3:M20,1,J3:J20,"not defined")`

Comment: You should not be using `COUNTA` here, when using `SUMPRODUCT` instead should be like this --> `=SUMPRODUCT(($M$3:$M$20=1)*($J$3:$J$20="not defined"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either of the one, refer image

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$9=1)*($B$2:$B$9="not defined"))

=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9,1,$B$2:$B$9,"not defined")
```

[image: Count Rows with Multiple Criteria]

Comment: What if I wanted to count when a row has any value in the Priority column AND "not defined" value in the Status column?

Comment: You mean to count both 1 and 0 as well --> `=SUMPRODUCT(($M$3:$M$20={1,0})*($J$3:$J$20="not defined"))`

Comment: Or just use COUNTIF only on the status column

Comment: Absolutely Correct @VincentvanderLinden Sir !!!